# BeanCreationException и IllegalAccessError или как правильно организовать слой для работы с БД

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

**UPDATE** вопрос решен. Было неправильное название метода List findByUser(User user), нужно List findByUserId(User user), так как у меня нет поля user, а есть userId

Я только начал изучать Spring и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть база данных вот такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у меня есть 5 классов-сущностей. Для каждой я хочу написать репозиторий(дао) и сервис. 
Я написал уже репозиторий и сервис для 3 сущносте (category, users, item).

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Category implements Serializable{
   //тут поля и геттеры и сеттеры к ним
}



public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {
    //методы
}


public interface CategoryService {
    //методы
}



@Service("categoryService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    //методы
}
```

То же самое для `Users` и `Item`.
Когда добавил репозиторий и сервис для `UserOrder` Spring начал ругаться:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userOrderRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches(PropertyReferenceException.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.<init>(PropertyReferenceException.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:408)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 43 more
```

Я предполагаю, что я неправильно организовую сам слой для работы с БД, но я делаю на основе примера найденного в интернете, поэтому не могу понять в чем моя ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот мой spring-config.xml:

```
   <!--@Transaction annotation support -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

   <!--Обеспечивает работу с транзакциями в Spring -->
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
          <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
   <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
          <!--Поставщик данных - hibernate-->
          <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
          </property>
          <!--поиск сущностей в этом пакете-->
          <property name="packagesToScan"
                    value="ua.a.pavlenko"/>
          <!--детали конфигурации поставщика постоянства (hibernate) -->
          <property name="jpaProperties">
                 <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                               org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                        </prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 </props>
          </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Datasource. Источник данных - база MySQL -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eshop" />
          <property name="username" value="root" />
          <property name="password" value="root" />
   </bean>

   <!--<bean id="categoryService" class="ua.a.pavlenko.service.impl.CategoryServiceImpl"/>-->

   <!--<bean id="category" class="ua.a.pavlenko.entity.Category"/>-->

   <!--Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's @Required and @Autowired and so on-->
   <context:annotation-config/>

   <!-- Need for Repository abstraction -->
   <jpa:repositories base-package="ua.a.pavlenko.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                     transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

   <!--Scanning components in base-package (look for annotations) -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="ua.a.pavlenko"/>
```

```
@Entity
@Table
public class UserOrder implements Serializable{
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long userOrderId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User userId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column
private Calendar date;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userOrderId")
private List<OrderedItem> orderedItemList;
//getters and setters
```

}

```
public interface UserOrderRepository extends CrudRepository{
    List findByUser(User user);
    List findByDate(Calendar date);
}
```

```
public interface UserOrderService {
    UserOrder findOne(long userOrderId);
    List findAll();
    List findByUser(User user);
    List findByDate(Calendar date);
    void delete(long userOrderId);
    void deleteAll();
    UserOrder addOrEditUserOrder(UserOrder userOrder);
}
```

```
@Service("userOrderService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserOrderServiceImpl implements UserOrderService {
```

```
@Autowired(required = true)
UserOrderRepository userOrderRepository;

public UserOrder findOne(long userOrderId) {
    return userOrderRepository.findOne(userOrderId);
}

public List<UserOrder> findAll() {
    return (List<UserOrder>) userOrderRepository.findAll();
}

public List<UserOrder> findByUser(User user) {
    return userOrderRepository.findByUser(user);
}

public List<UserOrder> findByDate(Calendar date) {
    return userOrderRepository.findByDate(date);
}

public void delete(long userOrderId) {
    userOrderRepository.delete(userOrderId);
}

public void deleteAll() {
    userOrderRepository.deleteAll();
}

public UserOrder addOrEditUserOrder(UserOrder userOrder) {
    return userOrderRepository.save(userOrder);
}
```

}

Comment: По-моему, если проблемы начались с добавлением какого-то кода, то надо привести в вопросе этот код. И `hibernate.dialect` в конфиге поправьте на подходящий для `mysql`.

Comment: Судя по исключению, несовпадение версий библиотек. Обновите spring.

Comment: @zRrr исправил диалект, добавил листинг классов

Comment: @zRrr спасибо помогли. обновил версию спринга и ошибки уже cnfkb другие, которые я смог исправить. Корень проблемы был в методе List findByUser(User user) интерфейса UserOrderRepository. Нужно было написать List findByUserId(User user), так как у меня поле называется userId

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решен. Было неправильное название метода List findByUser(User user), нужно List findByUserId(User user), так как у меня нет поля user, а есть userId